# Using RowSource Property to Fill ComboBox in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to fill a ComboBox with selections equal to the first column of a data table, and keep getting

> Run-Time error 380

I suppose I could use a loop and AddItem statements, but since I expect this to get large (several hundred entries), would prefer to stay away from loops that might slow down the execution.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
Private Sub ClientNameComboxAdd_Enter()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, UseRow As Long
Dim NameFind As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client Info")
LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Clients").Range.Rows.Count
If LastRow = 2 And sht.ListObjects("Clients").DataBodyRange(1, 1) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Can't Add a New Plan With No Clients Entered"
    Exit Sub
End If
ClientNameComboxAdd.RowSource = sht.ListObjects("Clients").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
End Sub
```

The problem is in the next-to-last line - ClientNameComboxAdd.RowSource ...  The first part, which comes into play before clients are added to the table, seems to work fine.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to create a named range referenced to the column of your table that contains the data you want. That new range will be dinamic, because it is associated with the range of your table (I guess you have inserted a table). Then right click on your combobox and set the Rowsource property using the name of the range you have created. That way the combobox data will be updated anytime the table changes. No need of VBA to do this from my point of view.

Comment: It seems to make a lot of sense, and it does eliminate the error code, but for some reason, it only picks up the first element of the range (for example, if I have a column with 3 entries, it only picks up the first in the combo box.  I did check to make sure that the range name was properly defined, and picking up all 3 items in the column. I also tried setting the RowSource this way with VBA code, and interestingly, while it threw no error, it didn't show anything in the Combo Box.  I think I may just go down the AddItem/RemoveItem road, since it should work. BTW, U R rite -i'm using a table

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way. No VBA code at all. Just Excel 100%.

First, I created a Table named "T_DATA" with 2 columns, COUNTRY and CONTINENT, and after that I added 3 records:

```
    Country         Continent
United States        America
Spain                 Europa
Germany               Europa
```

After that, I created a Range named RANGECOMBOBOX, and source is the Country column of my table. Check image:

[image]

You have to make sure this named range refers to the column of your table. In my case is just "=T_DATA[Country]".

After that, I Inserted the combobox and Right click on it, tab CONTROL, and I set the Entry Range as the named range I created before, in my case, RANGECOMBOBOX:

[image]

Third step is testing if the combobox get the values of the Country Column, and it does:

[image]

Now final test, I inserted 2 new records in my table (China and Japan values) and the combobox updates instantly, by just adding records to my table.

[image]

Hope this can give you a light in your task. Another option you have is doing the same I did but activate first the macro recorder and check the code. Maybe it can help you out with your issue.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Then try

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ClientNameComboxAdd.RowSource = "RangeCombobox"
End Sub
```

This worked on my userform, and the combobox loaded the countries. However, remember to unload and load again your form every time you insert new records into your table, to update the combobox

Comment: I appreciate your assistance - is your ComboBox a form control, instead of an ActiveX control?  I wonder if that makes any difference here.  My ComboBox is part of a fairly decent sized User Form (multi-page with 2 pages currently, and probably 5 or 6 when it's done), and for that reason needs to be ActiveX.

Comment: My combobox is not in a form. If your combobox is in a form, I updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I came from Google and I did not entirely like the intermediate ComboBox approach, so I tried using a direct reference to the table[column] and it seems to have worked.

If using Foxfire's example, all I had to do was

1. Place the ComboBox on my form
2. Set its RowSource property to `T_DATA[Country]` in the Designer - note how there is no `=` sign in front.

I assume setting this at runtime would work just as well.