# Run time error '380' Could not set RowSource property, Invalid property value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have encountered an error

> Run time error '380': Could not set RowSource property, Invalid property value.

What should I do?

I have three tabs: `Form`, `Product Search` and `Stock Data`.

I have already set up the name manager under formula tab  into this:

```
=OFFSET('Product Search'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Product Search'!$A:$A)-1,3)
```

This is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim RowNum As Long 
    Dim SearchRow As Long 

    RowNum = 2
    SearchRow = 2
    Worksheets("Product Search").Range("A2:I100").ClearContents

    Worksheets("Stock Data").Activate

    Do Until Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""
        If InStr(1, Cells(RowNum, 2).Value, txtKeywords.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Product Search").Cells(SearchRow, 2).Value = Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Product Search").Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value = Cells(RowNum, 2).Value
            Worksheets("Product Search").Cells(SearchRow, 3).Value = Cells(RowNum, 3).Value

            SearchRow = SearchRow + 1
        End If

        RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Loop

    If SearchRow = 2 Then
        MsgBox "No products were found that match your search criteria."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lstSearchResults.RowSource = "SearchResults"
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245937/using-rowsource-property-to-fill-combobox-in-excel-vba